Outlook XML add-in - Can't remove or move email
When user triggers the add-in button, I open a Dialog that has a button labeled "Delete the Mail" But I can't make it work. Target system uses Azure AD,
The problem starts with not getting user token silently, I have to open a Microsoft Auth Popup, Which is terrible for user experience.
const loginResponse = await msalApplication.loginPopup({ scopes: graphScopes });
const tokenResponse = await msalApplication.acquireTokenSilent({ scopes: graphScopes });

I have to call loginPopup at least once in order to acquireTokenSilent() to work. How can i get the token silently.
User already logged in to outlook so
    const tokenResponse = await msalApplication.acquireTokenSilent({ scopes: graphScopes });

should have worked. But it doesn't get the token and if i call
const loginResponse = await msalApplication.loginPopup({ scopes: graphScopes });

it opens popup briefly and closes.
